# Error when starting MongoDB on Windows: getnameinfo errno 10106

Tags: mongodb, winsock

I've gone through the installation instructions on MongoDB about five times now and I keep getting the same issue. I've googled and googled but can't really seem to find a good answer to this problem.

When I go to start the MongoDB service in the prompt(c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe), I get the following error:

```
exception in initAndListen:13082 getnameinfo error errno:10106 
The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.. terminating
```

From what I gathered, this is more of a Windows issue than something wrong with my Mongo setup? But I'm not sure how to get around it. Anybody else ever run into this?

Comment: probably a stupid question, but what exactly would entail "properly configured" ? is there anything special that I have to do with it for Mongo?

Comment: mean if you have a network connection on that machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code 10106 is about this [WinSock error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT [10106]: Service provider failed to initialize.
>   This error is returned if either a service provider's DLL could not be
>   loaded (LoadLibrary failed) or the provider's WSPStartup or NSPStartup
>   function failed.

To fix it, open cmd as admin, type the following and hit Enter.

```
netsh winsock reset
```

You can see this [link](https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/Resetting_Network_Adapter_%28Winsock_Reset%29) for more details.

Comment: thank you so much - I wasted countless time on this. This fixed my issue. thanks again!